# Gremlin: select last (or first, or all, etc.) from set property

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Given this vertex: `g.addV().property('numbers',1).property('numbers',2).property('numbers',3).next()`

I would like to select only the last value (3) in the `numbers` set. How can this be accomplished? I've reviewed the docs and not found a clear means of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
gremlin> g.V(0L).values('numbers').tail()
==>3
```